# Launch4j for jar to exe

Tags: java, xml, exe, launch4j

Can't seem to figure out why I my `JFileChooser` never shows up when I run my .exe file created by launch4j.  A lot of folks discuss mostly the class path on this error, but I'm failing to realize the solution.

Error 1:

```
no main manifest attribute in C:\Users\Documents\...\HPLCData.exe
```

Now if I change the class path to KFile.Main, then I get this error message

Error 2:

```
Error: Could not find or locate main class KFile.Main
```

Error 3:

Error: Could not find or locate main class KFile.class

Admittedly, I'm rather new to java and maybe the answer is staring me in the face or is obvious, sorry if so.  Otherwise, things I read point to an issue with the class path and I'm not entirely sure what I need to change.

Part of me wonders if it has something to do with the  part in the xml file generated, but I have no idea what would go there.  I've tried changing all kinda of strange things, the [closest post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class) I found had mentioned something about using the full class path.  Or maaybe there is a problem with the jar wrapping, but I don't think so as I double checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391562/launch4j-exe-still-needs-the-jar-file)

Here are the .xml files generated by launch4j to wrap the .exe file.

case 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch4jConfig>
  <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
  <headerType>console</headerType>
  <jar>C:\Users\red\Documents\Java Modules\Introductory Files\HPLCData.jar</jar>
  <outfile>C:\Users\red\Documents\Java Modules\Introductory Files\HPLCData.exe</outfile>
  <errTitle></errTitle>
  <cmdLine></cmdLine>
  <chdir>.</chdir>
  <priority>normal</priority>
  <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
  <supportUrl></supportUrl>
  <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
  <restartOnCrash>false</restartOnCrash>
  <manifest></manifest>
  <icon></icon>
  <jre>
    <path>C:\Users\red\Documents\Java Modules\Introductory Files\</path>
    <bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>
    <bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback>
    <minVersion>1.6.0_1</minVersion>
    <maxVersion></maxVersion>
    <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
    <runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits>
  </jre>
  <versionInfo>
    <fileVersion>1.0.0.0</fileVersion>
    <txtFileVersion>version 1</txtFileVersion>
    <fileDescription>Manage HPLC Data</fileDescription>
    <copyright>Kemin 2016</copyright>
    <productVersion>1.0.0.0</productVersion>
    <txtProductVersion>version 1</txtProductVersion>
    <productName>HPLC Data</productName>
    <companyName>Red</companyName>
    <internalName>Red</internalName>
    <originalFilename>HPLCData.exe</originalFilename>
  </versionInfo>
</launch4jConfig>
```

Case 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch4jConfig>
  <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
  <headerType>console</headerType>
  <jar>C:\Users\red\Documents\Java Modules\Introductory Files\HPLCData.jar</jar>
  <outfile>C:\Users\red\Documents\Java Modules\Introductory Files\HPLCData.exe</outfile>
  <errTitle></errTitle>
  <cmdLine></cmdLine>
  <chdir>.</chdir>
  <priority>normal</priority>
  <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
  <supportUrl></supportUrl>
  <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
  <restartOnCrash>false</restartOnCrash>
  <manifest></manifest>
  <icon></icon>
  <classPath>
    <mainClass>KFile.Main</mainClass>
  </classPath>
  <jre>
    <path>C:\Users\red\Documents\Java Modules\Introductory Files\</path>
    <bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>
    <bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback>
    <minVersion>1.6.0_1</minVersion>
    <maxVersion></maxVersion>
    <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
    <runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits>
  </jre>
  <versionInfo>
    <fileVersion>1.0.0.0</fileVersion>
    <txtFileVersion>version 1</txtFileVersion>
    <fileDescription>Manage HPLC Data</fileDescription>
    <copyright>Kemin 2016</copyright>
    <productVersion>1.0.0.0</productVersion>
    <txtProductVersion>version 1</txtProductVersion>
    <productName>HPLC Data</productName>
    <companyName>Red</companyName>
    <internalName>Red</internalName>
    <originalFilename>HPLCData.exe</originalFilename>
  </versionInfo>
</launch4jConfig>
```

case 3:

```
 <manifest></manifest>
  <icon></icon>
  <classPath>
    <mainClass>KFile.class</mainClass>
  </classPath>
```

Java code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;



public class KFile extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Path currPath = Paths.get("");
        String currDir = currPath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
        System.out.println(currDir);


        File dataDir = chooseDir("open");
        File destDir = chooseDir("save");


        if(!destDir.exists()) {

            try {
                destDir.mkdir();
            }
            catch (SecurityException se) {
                System.out.println("Couldn't make directory!");
            }

        }
        int n = 0;
        if(dataDir.exists()) {
            Collection<Path> allDir  = new ArrayList<Path>();
            try {
                addTree(dataDir.toPath(),allDir);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error with scanning");
            }
            for( Path thisPath : allDir ) {
                if(thisPath.toString().contains("Report.pdf")) {
                    Path thisDir = thisPath.getParent();
                    File f = new File(thisDir.toString(), "\\Report.txt");
                    n = n + 1;
                    String fileName = "Report " + n + ".pdf";
                    try {
                        fileName = parseName(f);
                        System.out.println(fileName);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    File thisFile = new File(destDir + "\\" + fileName);

                    try {
                        copyFile(thisPath.toFile(),thisFile);
                    } catch ( IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }


    }


    public static boolean copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
        //create file if it doesn't exist.
        if(!destFile.exists()) {
            destFile.createNewFile();           
        }

        FileChannel source = null;
        FileChannel destination = null;

        try {
            source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
            destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        }
        finally {
            if(source != null) {
                source.close();
            }
            if(destination != null) {
                destination.close();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }

    public static File chooseDir(String s) {

        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("HPLC Data Transfer");
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.pack();
        myFrame.setVisible(true);

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        File currDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Documents");

        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(currDir);

        int choice = 0;
        if (s.equals("save")) {
            choice = chooser.showSaveDialog(myFrame);
        } else {
            choice = chooser.showOpenDialog(myFrame);
        }

        myFrame.setVisible(false);
        myFrame.removeAll();
        myFrame.dispose();
        if(choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("You chose to open: " + chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
            return chooser.getSelectedFile();
        }
        return new File("");
    }

    static String parseName(File f) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f), "UTF-16"));

        int lnCnt = 32;
        String[] fileData = new String[lnCnt];

        for (int i = 0; i < lnCnt; i++) {
            fileData[i] = textReader.readLine();
        }

        String name = fileData[1].substring(13) + ".pdf";

        textReader.close();
        return name;
    }

    static void addTree(Path directory, final Collection<Path> all)
        throws IOException {
    Files.walkFileTree(directory, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                throws IOException {
            all.add(file);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: I would have expected the error to refer to `KFile.Main`, not `KFile.class`. Any chance you have `<mainClass>KFile.class</mainClass>` ?

Comment: The first error is because you don't have a [`Main-Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) attribute in the manifest file that you used to create the jar. I would echo @MiserableVariable's comment on the second error.

Comment: Thanks I guys, I'm a noob.  I added a third case, I was trying different things and tried both KFile.Main and KFile.class but forgot to fix that in my xml file that I copied and pasted.  I added a third case which reflects this

Comment: What is the complete name of class including the package? Show us the java code.

Comment: @MiserableVariable sorry!  Didn't know it was going to be needed, thought sense it worked with command line, the code was fine.

Comment: Only the declaration was needed, to identify the class name. It wasn't clear to me if with `KFile.Main` the name of package was `KFile` and name of class `Main`. You don't have a package declaration. It seems the tool will call the `Main` method of whatever class you specify. Ergo, the declaration you need is `<mainClass>KFile</mainClass>`

Comment: @MiserableVariable Thanks!  Now the .exe works!  Just have a fun runtime error now!  Woohoo, hahaha.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shows in the messages, Launch4J seems to call the `Main` method of whatever class is specified as `mainClass` in the configuration. So:

- For `KFile.class` you need to have a class named `class` in `package KFile`. This is not even possible, since you cannot have a `class` named `class`; is a reserved word
- For `KFile.Main` you need to have a class named `Main` in `package KFile`.

You do not have a package declaration, your class `KFile` is in the default package. So the declaration you need is

```
<mainClass>KFile</mainClass>
```